# "branch/tag" through Tortoise SVN dialog is forbidden

Tags: tortoisesvn, branch, tagging

I am facing a problem with TortoiseSVN (my client version is 1.6.16 and the SVNversion is 1.4.6.28521).

The projectA project has the classical architecture, with three folder: trunk, branches and tags.

I have rights to Read and Write from a projectA folders (tags,branches and trunk).

While working in the trunk, there is no issue, everything works fine. The only problem is that when a release time comes (or branching time comes), and I want to create a tag (a branch), I want to use the TortoiseSVN dialog "branch/tag". Then I choose the origin from the trunk or the revision o nthe trunk i need, and choose the "To URL" like "http://..../projectA/tags/v2.0".

[image: Example of branching/tagging from TortoiseSVN dialog]

After clicking "OK", it will let me know that the access to "http://...../projectA/" is forbidden.

The only solution right now, is to checkout the "projectA/tags" folder to a local folder. Then in this "projectA/tags" folder I will create one new folder with the name of the tag I want to create, and I am able to commit it without any problem.

I don't want to manually create the folder of the tag/branch like this, andwould rather like to use the "branch/tag" feature of TortoiseSVN.

Anyone has an idea about this issue ?

Comment: Did you tried to copy from 1) Working Copy (updated to HEAD) 2) CLI 3) Repo-Browser? You lost authentication some way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a recommendation in Subversion (at least on Windows with TortoiseSVN) to use the same major version as the server. You are allowed to ignore that recommendation, and most of the time, it does not hurt, but here you may have a case where it makes a difference. You should at least check if

- the server could be upgraded to 1.6.x XOR
- the client (your installation) could be downgraded to 1.4.x

However, your client will ( in the second case ) no longer work with your checkout directories. Branching has changed a lot from version 1.4.x to 1.6.x, so you will face a hard time if you have to use a 1.6.x client with a 1.4.x server.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I will see this point with the sysadmin and let you know.